# Schengen exit stamp on old passport

Tags: customs-and-immigration, schengen, schengen-visas, passport-stamps, milan

i travelled to schengen zone from pakistan on a 6 month mutientry visa.i exited the schengen area from milan malpensa airport.the passport control officer stamped exit on one of my old passports instead of the latest one.will that make any difference to me for my future travel prospects.i stayed for 5 days in total.

Comment: Was the visa on an old passport? Why did you present the old passport?

Comment: I can't answer your specific question, but anecdotally I have had stamps put in both canceled and valid (at different times) so I asked a border officer and he told me it didn't really matter to them, as long as there was a stamp.  This was entering the US though, not exiting Schengen, so the situation is different.

Comment: visa was on new one.my 3 passports were attached together by a sticker.thats why i gave them all 3.how could i imagine that he would put stamp on the invalid one.i saw that afterwards

Answer (score 3):

Attaching old and new passports are sometimes done, but this is why it is not (or at least no longer) a good practice.

It is extremely unusual to present ***three*** passports to a border officer unless specifically demanded or special circumstances exist (e.g. visas or entry stamps in old passport).

As Schengen entries and exits records are based on stamps only (for now), the stamps may be and often are requested (especially when applying for visas) to determine if one has violated the duration of stay authorized.

You must be prepared to provide passports that have Schengen stamps, when you apply for another Schengen visa or enter a Schengen country again, and be prepared to answer questions as to why the stamp was on an invalid passport. If they are satisfied with your explanation and accept that you did not overstay, it should not be a problem for your future travel. To justify such explanation, proofs that you indeed left the Schengen area would be helpful. So you should probably keep your flight reservation records and boarding pass and any taxi or hotel receipts outside the Schengen area shortly after the date of exit.